# Non-medical interpretation of birthmarks

Tags: single-word-requests

A recent off-topic question on the worldbuilding stack [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/195709/unique-birthmark-a-witch-riding-a-broom-with-outlined-dress-and-hat-very-detail) aroused my curiosity as to whether there might be a specific word that fits.

I'm looking for a word to describe "the non-medical interpretation, but mystical or religious attachment of meaning and significance to birthmarks".

The reading of tea-leaves is tasseography, the reading of entrails would be haruspicy or extispicy.

Dictionary searches around birthmarks keep leading to the word superstition.

> belief that is not based on human reason or scientific knowledge, but
> is connected with old ideas about magic, etc.

<sup>[Cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/superstition) 2021</sup>

There are many websites [referencing](https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2015/04/the-odd-superstition-behind-birthmarks/389958/) the reading and interpretation of [birthmarks](https://www.thebeijinger.com/blog/2019/06/10/birthmarks-kiss-angel-or-mark-devil), none of which name the practice uniquely with a single word or phrase.

Is there a single word that describes the practice, beyond the generic one, superstition?

Comment: I'm inclined to trust your research that interpreting birthmarks has no special name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**maculomancy**, **moleomancy**, or **moleosophy** are all occasionally encountered but none seems to have made it into the OED or most other dictionaries.

[Wikipedia's article Moleosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moleosophy) says "Moleosophy or moleomancy is a technique of divination and fortune telling based upon the observation and interpretation of bodily marks"; as the name suggests, it primarily refers to moles but can also be used of other marks.

Maculomancy is from the Latin ["macula"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/macula#Latin) meaning spot, speckle, stain, according to [Wordsense](https://www.wordsense.eu/maculomancy/); it doesn't have a Wikipedia page but is a redirect to moleosophy.

These words seem more or less confined to websites on the occult and divination, and to online dictionaries that accept user-submitted words. Perhaps not suitable for formal documents, but OK in casual writing.

Uses include the website [Occult World](https://occult-world.com/maculomancy/) which discusses maculomancy, and some occult books on Google Books, such as [*The Fortune-telling Book* by Raymond Buckland](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Fortune_telling_Book/_DTXAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=maculomancy).

The classic text on interpreting moles is *On Moles* by [Melampus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melampus), but it doesn't appear to use any such word.

Comment: Splendid Stuart. I'd be surprised if this could be topped, yet it's given me an idea for more research.